# Generating pkcs12 for ios push notification server

Tags: ios, openssl, push-notification, certificate, pkcs#12

Following procedure does not work,openssl at 4th step raises "No certificate matches private key". It works without -certfile parameter so is it really required? I saw same procedure at several places on the net. So is it really appropriate or am i doing something wrong?
Also OS X procedure only says to export certificate but should not it be both cert and pkey.

OpenSSL

Here is how to create a PKCS12 format file using open ssl, you will need your developer private key (which can be exported from the keychain) and the CertificateSigningRequest??.certSigningRequest

1. Convert apn_developer_identity.cer (der format) to pem: `openssl x509 -in apn_developer_identity.cer -inform DER -out apn_developer_identity.pem -outform PEM`
2. Next, Convert p12 private key to pem (requires the input of a minimum 4 char password): `openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out private_dev_key.pem -in private_dev_key.p12`
3. (Optional): If you want to remove password from the private key: `openssl rsa -out private_key_noenc.pem -in private_key.pem`
4. Take the certificate and the key (with or without password) and create a PKCS#12 format file: `openssl pkcs12 -export -in apn_developer_identity.pem -inkey private_key_noenc.pem -certfile CertificateSigningRequest??.certSigningRequest -name "apn_developer_identity" -out apn_developer_identity.p12`

   http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/wiki/HowToCreatePKCS12Certificate

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: I know that tutorial. He does not use the CSR file, even he says to throw it. So, i want to know the point of CSR file in openssl command here.

Comment: Take a look a this -- hope it helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744310/how-to-install-apple-push-certificate-on-windows-server