# Trying to POST to APNS - System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: apple-push-notifications, tls1.2

I am relatively new to much of this and attempting to send notifications to APNS API using asp.net 4.5 in a windows console program (eventually will be a Windows Service).

But my code below in the console program is returning an error exception in the "response.ErrorException" with the following:

**System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.**

*I've spent many hours trying to figure out what is wrong without any success. Unfortunately I am working by myself so any advice or help is appreciated!*

Here is what I have done so far:

- Downloaded the APNS certificate from Apple and downloaded on my local Windows 7 machine.
- Used the instructions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744310/how-to-install-apple-push-certificate-on-windows-server) to install the certificate on my local machine.
- The certificate is installed on the Local User Store as mentioned to using Postman.
- Tested the HTTP POST with Postman and got a successful response (200 OK)

Using Postman code generation, and adding a little of my own code taken from other posts, I inserted the following code into my console application:

```
    try
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
            | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
            | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
            | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

         var client = new RestClient("https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/cMQCjCHfLAM:APA91bF2D............IIZJ85henm5zPgY5");
         client.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection();
         client.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate("apn_development.p12", "testpassword");
         var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
         request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
         request.AddHeader("apns-topic", "com.test.test");
         request.AddHeader("host", "api.development.push.apple.com");
         request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
         request.AddHeader("apns-priority", "10");
         request.AddHeader("apns-expiration", "0");
         request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\r\n  \"aps\": {\r\n    \"alert\": {\r\n      \"title\": \"testtest\",\r\n      \"body\": \"This is a test.\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"badge\": 0\r\n  }\r\n}\r\n", ParameterType.RequestBody);
         IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

         if (response.ErrorException != null)
         {
             log.Error(response.ErrorMessage.FirstOrDefault());
             Debug.WriteLine(response.ErrorMessage.FirstOrDefault());
         }

       }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       log.Error(ex);
       Debug.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
   }
```

I also added System.net trace logging and got the following though I don't know what they mean.  Here is a small snippet of the trace log:

```
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7912] 00000395 : 63 6F 6E 64 69 74 69 6F-6E 73 20 6F 66 20 75 73 : conditions of us
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7912] 000003A5 : 65 20 61 6E 64 2F 6F 72-20 63 65 72 74 69 66 69 : e and/or certifi
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7912] 000003B5 : 63 61 74 69 6F 6E 20 70-72 61 63 74 69 63 65 20 : cation practice 
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7912] 000003C5 : 73 74 61 74 65 6D 65 6E-74 73 2E 30 39 06 08 2B : statements.09..+
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7912] 000003D5 : 06 01 05 05 07 02 01 16-2D 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F : ........-http://
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7912] 000003E5 : 77 77 77 2E 61 70 70 6C-65 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 63 65 : www.apple.com/ce
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7912] 000003F5 : 72 74 69 66 69 63 61 74-65 61 75 74 68 6F 72 69 : rtificateauthori
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7912] Exiting     Socket#44665200::Receive()   -> Int32#2576
    System.Net Information: 0 : [7912] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = 52f5bc8:53198b8, targetName = api.development.push.apple.com, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
    System.Net Information: 0 : [7912] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=ContinueNeeded).
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7912] Socket#44665200::Receive()
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7912] Data from   Socket#44665200::Receive
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7912] 00000000 : 15 03 03 00 02                                  : .....
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7912] Exiting Socket#44665200::Receive()   -> Int32#5
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7912] Socket#44665200::Receive()
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7912] Data from Socket#44665200::Receive
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7912] 00000005 : 02 28                                           : .(
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7912] Exiting Socket#44665200::Receive()   -> Int32#2
    System.Net Information: 0 : [7912] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = 52f5bc8:53198b8, targetName = api.development.push.apple.com, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
    System.Net Information: 0 : [7912] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=IllegalMessage).
    System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [7912] Socket#44665200::Dispose()
    System.Net Error: 0 : [7912] Exception in HttpWebRequest#22369618:: - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
    System.Net Error: 0 : [7912] Exception in HttpWebRequest#22369618::EndGetRequestStream - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
```